# web socket url with domain name of backend container but doesnot resolve into ip of backend container

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose, websocket, dockerfile, django-channels

i made a docker container for react app and another for django app . now when i make a websocket call

```
const socket = new WebSocket(
      // `ws://${WEB_SOCKET}:${WEB_SOCKET_PORT}/ws/lobby/`//this works when i feed ip of django app
      'wss://backend:8000/ws/lobby/'

    );
```

it says
`home.jsx:9 WebSocket connection to 'wss://backend:8000/ws/lobby/' failed:\`

here is docker-compose.yml file

```
services:
    django-backend:
      container_name: backend 
      restart : always 
      build:
        context: ./server
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      depends_on:
        - postgres
        - redis 
      volumes:
        - ./server:/app 
.
.
    chess-frontend:
      container_name: frontend
      restart : always 
      build:
        context: ./chess-front
        target: development  
      ports:
        - "5173:5173"
      volumes:
        - ./chess-front:/usr/src/app
```

presently i am checking ip of django container and manually updating the web socket url .my question is

- is there a way to make websocket url using domain name (ie. container name )
- if not can i automatically get django container's ip in docker-compose up and update in url .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after research i found that web socket urls with domain name of host container do not resolve into ip of host container , even if they are in same network.

[check this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760641/open-a-websocket-connexion-from-a-docker-container-to-another-able-to-ping-cont)

however i came up with a way to automatically update the ip of host container by running bash script  before the frontend container starts . This fetches ip of backend container and updates my .env file variable

Dockerfile of react app

```
FROM node:alpine AS base 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install 

FROM  base AS development 
COPY . .
COPY update_env.sh /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 5173
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/update_env.sh
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm run dev"]
FROM base AS production
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5173
CMD ["npm" , "run" , "build"]
```

update_env.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
BACKEND_CONTAINER_NAME="backend"
ENV_FILE_PATH="./.env"
BACKEND_IP=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $BACKEND_CONTAINER_NAME)

if [ -n "$BACKEND_IP" ]; then
    # Checks if VITE_IP already exists in the .env file
    if grep -q '^VITE_IP=' "$ENV_FILE_PATH"; then
        # Updates the existing VITE_IP value
        sed -i "s/^VITE_IP=.*/VITE_IP=$BACKEND_IP/" "$ENV_FILE_PATH"
    else
        # Adds VITE_IP to the .env file
        echo "VITE_IP=$BACKEND_IP" >> "$ENV_FILE_PATH"
    fi

    echo "Updated VITE_IP in .env file."
else
    echo "Error: Unable to obtain the IP address of the backend container."
fi
```

docker-compose.yml

```
chess-frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    restart : always 
    build:
      context: ./chess-front
      target: development  
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    volumes:
      - ./chess-front:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - django-backend
    command: sh -c "/usr/src/app/update_env.sh && npm run dev"
```

now whenever container restarts , i get ip of backend container automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In Docker, containers can be accessed by their names within the same network.
You can create a network using the docker network create command.
For example:
docker network create my-network
Then, when you run your containers, add them to the network using the --network flag.
For example:
docker run --name backend --network my-network

YML update would be to specify networks as per below.

```
version: '3'
services:
  django-backend:
    container_name: backend
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./server
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
    networks:
      - my-network
  chess-frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./chess-front
      target: development
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    volumes:
      - ./chess-front:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Remember to replace the port numbers (8000 and 5173) with the actual ports used by your backend and frontend services, respectively.